# Use OrchardCMS, Umbraco or DotNetNuke as a component in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net, integration, umbraco, orchardcms

`OrchardCMS`, `Umbraco` and `DotNetNuke` are CMSes in .Net galaxy. They work as stand alone applications well. Suppose I have a requirement that need CMS features in an another ASP.NET MVC application. I do not like to implement CMS again in the application. Rather I like to use current CMSes as a component of application.

Is it possible at all to use for example OrhcardCMS as a component of my MVC application? It is ideal to have relations between CMS and application itself, for example I can load entities from CMS, update them etc.

I know there are integration techniques in .Net. For example ASP.NET Identity integrates with ASP.NET applications in core level, but view (CSHTMLs) must be copied and customized in most cases. Or Hangfire and ELMAH that integrates with an application without need to copy view (cshtml, html, css) to the target application. Indeed it is good to know that integration methods are available regarding plugging CMSes into ASP.NET applications.

Comment: There is also [BetterCMS](http://www.bettercms.com/), which is a NuGet package so can be integrated

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you more about **Umbraco** as I don't know other CMS as much as this one. There is a whole course / training for those who want to integrate their apps with Umbraco: https://umbraco.com/products-and-support/training/umbraco-application-integration/. So yes, it's possible and it's even suggested way from my perspective to use already done piece of software rather than building the wheel once again.

Umbraco is an ASP.NET MVC application. You can use Umbraco components, backoffice, membership and everything else CMSish delivered out of box and still you're able to write and use your business logic, controllers and everything else what you've created inside your ASP.NET MVC / C# app. Still, it's an ASP.NET app, so you can use anything what you want from the .NET world. We're using ELMAH.io for example to take care of logging and keeping the errors in the cloud. We're also using a ton of 3rd party, both open-source and commercial tools and softwares to do multiple things around our web components. Umbraco is not blocking us from using them or anything else. I like to consider Umbraco as a framework or library helping us to deal with content editing and giving us a massive number of opportunities to offer for our clients or editors.

Comment: Indeed I have experiences with OrhardCMS before but never tried Umbraco. It looks promising as "it's even suggested way from my perspective to use already done piece of software rather than building the wheel once again.". So I will try it. Hope it is compliant with ASP.NET Core too.

Comment: It will be in the future, more polished and cleaned release. Find more about experiences of one from the Core team devs here: http://shazwazza.com/post/umbraco-cli-running-on-aspnet-core/ and have fun with Umbraco!

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for OrchardCMS, there are some questions touching this subject already, see

[Reusing Orchard's Core to build another extensibility framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8886388/3936440)

[Extracting a Module from Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29559197/3936440)

If it's possible for you then try to setup Orchard as the base system and move your MVC application in a module. This will be much easier than trying to cut out peaces of Orchard. In return you get amazing possibilites when running Orchard as the underlying framework, e.g. Localization, Modules, Themes, the whole user / role management etc.

OrchardCMS 2 is currently developed towards single components that can be reused in any application but it's far from finished yet.

Comment: The application itself is a large application and CMS is just one of its features. It does not looks logical to the application to be a module on OrchardCMS.