# How to add Orchard CMS to existing C# MVC5 project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am developing a website using C# MVC5 in visual studio 2015. Now I need to add CMS functionality to some pages. I am planning to add Orchard cms to my project. I have downloaded OrchardWeb zip file from orchardproject.net and the zip file contains files and folders like in the give screenshot.[[screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzlCc.png)
How can I add these files to my visual studio mvc project to add CMS functionalities without affecting my existing controlles, models and view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use OrchardCMS, Umbraco or DotNetNuke as a component in ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501763/use-orchardcms-umbraco-or-dotnetnuke-as-a-component-in-asp-net-application)

Comment: In my experience OrchardCMS is your web application, and you can add static and dynamic content within the framework. I haven't personally seen it bolted on to an existing website, you may encounter issues around authentication etc.

Comment: Can you please suggest a perfect  CMS  to add to an existing C# MVC project?

Comment: You could write your own or look at using an existing framework and trying to port your own code into it. With orchard CMS for example you can add your own controllers and views like any MVC website,  so you could setup an instance of that and then look to move your bespoke functionalities into it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Orchard 1 to an existing MVC project is virtually impossible (if not, at least impractical). Unless you keep Orchard 1 as a separate project and expose content via a Web API (either using an existing module that is in the works, or by creating your own module exposing content via a Web API). Your MVC5 application could then fetch content from the CMS via the web api.

Adding Orchard Core (a complete rewrite of Orchard for ASp.NET Core) is a different story. If you are at all able to migrate to ASP.NET Core, then adding a CMS to your site is [as simple as adding a NuGet package](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/getting-started-with-orchard-core-as-a-nuget-package).